# Blog Newsletter Delivery Day

Tags: discussion

Why is the newsletter sent in the middle of the week on Tuesday?
Can we change this to some other day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why is the newsletter sent in the middle of the week on Tuesday?**

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100194/139866),

> <sup>* we [searched Google for "best day of week to send email newsletter"](http://www.google.com/search?q=best%20day%20of%20week%20to%20send%20email%20newsletter) and Tuesday seemed popular</sup>

**Can we change this to some other day?**

I don't think we can: I think the algorithm is hard-coded and not user-configurable nor site-configurable.

There was at the time a [request to implement an option like that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100569/139866), but it wasn't a popular request (attracting only 5 up-votes and 5 down-votes), and so that request now has the `status-declined` tag.

---

FWIW that was apparently somewhat of a relief to [the person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99782/dont-send-all-newsletters-on-the-same-day/100194#comment255610_100194) who might have had to help implement that feature, who commented,

> phew, less work for me :)

I think that in general it's difficult to persuade Stack Exchange to change the current software.

One example is [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254375/139866) which has 30 up-votes but which so far as we know is not scheduled for implementation.

There are currently [19000 feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) of which 2000 have been completed and 1000 declined.

Comment: That answer seems oriented for marketing. This is a sangha and i think a more appropriate day would be the weekend so that people can read and write better replies.

Comment: I updated my answer: I don't think we have the ability to configure it.

Comment: That freaking sucks. But then again I can't think of any newsletter where you can choose the day to receive the digest.